# Getting error while using any ng statement

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I have just installed node and npm in my ubuntu system. I installed Angular CLI. now when I use **ng** statement **e.g. ng new test-project**, it gives me below error:

```
----Mg: -- watch
```

Screenshot: 
[image]

Can one please help me, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Close the terminal and open it and check node --version, npm --version and ng --version, then try ng new test-project.

Comment: I tried this, but shows the same.  when I use ng --version , it shows the above text.

Comment: Looks like you open emacs or something. Do you have a weird alias in bash for some reason? What do you get if you type `alias` in the terminal?

Comment: If I type "alias", it gives me : 
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'

Answer (score 1):

Try these step

Install Node.js on Ubuntu

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x

sudo apt install -y nodejs
```

Then

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following mentioned steps:

- This is the terminal editor on the 'ng' alias. Uninstall it with `sudo apt purge ng-common ng-latin`
- Try again installing `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

If the problem still persists, do tell me if I can help you in anyway.

Comment: Hi Niraj, I tried this. it installed successfully, but giving the same result.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes, IF you need I can give you access of my PC.

Comment: Type `ng` and press enter and let me see what is the result.

Comment: got the same, This screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YND3k.png

Comment: Were you able to remove using the above mentioned purge command?

Comment: I removed node, ng with uninstall as well as purge, but after installing ng-cli, I am getting the same.

Comment: It says:  Package 'ng' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200379/discussion-between-niraj-patel-and-ronak-patel).